# Horizontal and vertical lines in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, flash

[[image: strange lines in Google Chrome]<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHZey.jpg)

I see vertical and horizontal lines in Google Chrome on some pages (probably on pages contain Flash). OS X 10.7.4, Chrome 19.0.1084.46

**Chrome is fresh installed**, any idea what is that?

EDIT:

It happens only on pages with Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps for Chrome version 19:

1. Type `chrome://flags` in URL bar
2. Locate the following entry "Composited render layer borders"
3. Make sure it is set to "Enable"
4. Restart your browser and then check!

Comment: Ha! I disabled that feature, thanks mate. Why that thing was enabled at freshly installed Chrome?...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are running a web designer extension.

If that is the case, go to Chrome preferences and disable the extensions.

Comment: As I wrote is fresh installed Chrome...